# Chart with time in y-axis

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, ionic-framework

I need a chart for an ionic app that use time in the y-axis, something like this: [image]

The only thing I have been able to find that works like this is googles timeline chart: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline.  Problem with that is, they do not allow offline use and that is something I must have.  Has anyone seen anything that will work for this?  I have been working with amCharts, but they only allow parseDates to be used on the category(x) axis.

Answer (score 1):

ZingChart might be of interest to you. The y-axis on top is as simple as creating a `scale-y-2` object (and you can set the original `scale-y` axis to `visible: 0`).

The overlapping bars are achieved with a normal multi-series bar chart with `bars-overlap` set to 100% inside the plot object, and one of the series `bar-width`s set to 80% (or any percentage you'd like to use). Check out the included snippet for the code and chart.

As for using time for your y-axis values, the library provides the `transform` object that will [transform Unix timestamps into various date/time formats](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/features/data-formatting/#data__date__time). You can [read more about it](http://www.zingchart.com/docs/json-attributes-syntax/scale-objects/transform/) in the docs.

I'm on the ZingChart team, so if you have any questions about implementation, just give us a holler!

```js
var myChart = {
    "type":"hbar",
 "plotarea":{

 },
    "scale-y-2":{
        "values":["3pm","4pm","5pm","6pm","7pm"]
    },
    "scale-y":{
        "visible":false
    },
 "plot":{
        "bars-overlap":"100%"
 },
 "series":[
  {
    "values":[20,5,3,4]
  },
        {
            "values":[18,8,4,5],
            "bar-width":"80%"
        }
 ]
};

zingchart.render({
  data: myChart,
  id: "myChart",
  width: "100%"
 
});
```

```css
#myChart {
  width: 100%;  
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.zingchart.com/zingchart.min.js"></script>
<div id="myChart"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)

They're pretty customizable and will work offline.

**Edit**

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f7bvvk29/1/)

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar'
},
yAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    opposite: true
}
```

Comment: links might dead in future, better you put at least the concept

Comment: I dont see any that have the ability to use time in the y-axis

Comment: @esastincy The above is an example of time along the y-axis. However, from your screenshot above it looks more like you're wanting to mirror the x-axis. If so, you need to use 'opposite: true'. http://jsfiddle.net/c4uocron/ - A simple example based on one of the Highcharts examples.

Comment: @dan75 In your example, the population is the y axis.

Comment: @esastincy Using the two above JSFiddle examples you can get what you're after - http://jsfiddle.net/f7bvvk29/1/

Comment: Hi @dan75.   This isn't going to work the way I need it to. That would be perfect for converting into # of minutes or hours.  But I need it to be actual times i.e 11AM, 12PM, etc...